# Derived class calling parent class's method that calls an overriden virtual method calls the wrong method

Tags: c++, overriding, signature, virtual-functions, default-parameters

First of all, sorry for the confusing title. I have no idea how to word this properly.

The problem is not really a problem, but rather something that I don't know how to implement.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Parent
{
public:
    virtual void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Parent's foo" << std::endl;
    }
    void bar()
    {
        foo();
    }
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Child's foo" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Child c;

    c.bar();

    return 0;
}
```

When the code above runs, it prints out`Child's foo`.

However the same code, BUT with the child classes foo definition being`void foo(bool def = true)`Prints out `Parent's foo`.

Is there anyway to call the child's version of foo instead of the parent's one if the definitions missmatch?

Comment: No this is not possible if the definitions mismatch.

Comment: Since the Child is changing the signature of foo, you could also consider making a different function name.  Why?  Because foo is the API of the parent, and when a Child is used for where Parent is allowed those places will use the Parent's public API.  Having Child's foo with a different signature confuses the two things, making it harder to reuse (i.e., polymorphism) Child as a Parent for code expecting a Parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not, if you want to add extra parameters, even default ones, you can create an overloaded function explicitly, which behaves similar in most cases to the caller.

```
#include <iostream>
class Parent
{
public:
    virtual void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Parent's foo" << std::endl;
    }
    void bar()
    {
        foo();
    }
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    virtual void foo(bool def) // virtual if another subclass needs to override
    {
        std::cout << "Child's foo def = " << def << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void foo()override //override and virtual optional here
    {
        foo(true);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Child c;

    c.bar();
    c.foo();
    c.foo(true);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't add `virtual` to `foo(bool)` by default. If I have to add a `virtual`, it would be for `Parent` destructor.

Answer (score 1):

This is purely a function of when a function is overridden in C++.

In C++, function overriding is done according to the "signature" of member functions:

- unqualified name
- exact parameters list in the declaration (excluding implicit `this`)
- qualification of the `this` implicit parameter

Obviously, by definition, the type of the `this` parameter *cannot* match exactly, as by definition the type must be a pointer to a derived class.

*[Note about cv-qualification on parameters:*

The parameters in the declaration *as seen by caller* must be exactly the same, that is after removal of meaningless cv-qualifiers on object copies: these are cv-qualifiers on local variables inside the function body, and that's only meaningful in a function definition.

```
void f(const int i); // takes an int by value; const is meaningless
void f(int i); // redeclaration of the same function

// redeclaration of the same function yet again
void f(const int ci) { // const is meaningful here
  ci = 1; // error
}
```

*--end note]*

> However the same code, BUT with the child classes foo definition
>   being `void foo(bool def = true)` Prints out Parent's foo.

Because there is no match of the parameters lists: **an empty parameter list is only matched by an empty parameter list**.

You need to replace the default argument with two overloaded functions here, with no forwarding to the other:

```
void foo(bool def); // new function signature 

void foo() { // overrides Parent's member
  foo(true);
}
```

With long complex a parameters list, it's easy to change a type and create a new function signature instead of overriding a base class virtual function; it's also easy to get the capitalisation wrong or spelling wrong (think English vs. US spelling). In general, getting the name of a function wrong (or any other name: of a type, of a template, of a variable...) causes a compilation error because that name with the small spelling change wasn't declared. But with a raw declaration of a member with the intent of overriding a base class declaration, there is no hint that you tried to do that and the compiler will not warn you (it might warn for hiding a base class declaration, but this is different). Explicitly marking a declaration intended to be an override with the `virtual` keyword doesn't help, introducing a new virtual function isn't the intent.

That was the sad state of affairs after the first version of the C++ standard was formalized. Now it's different.

If you want to be sure that you are indeed overriding a base class declaration, you can now use the `override` keyword:

```
class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    void foo(bool def);
    void foo() override {
      foo(true);
    }
};
```